# dominant weights

Tags: rt.representation-theory

why does a fundamental representation of SL(n) have only one dominant weight? I am asking this because /\i(v) is a fundamental representation , but that can happen only if theres only one dominant weight and all others are conjugates under the weyl group action to it.

Comment: Every irreducible representation of SL(n) has only one dominant weight. This *should be* proven in any book on representations of Lie groups, as long as it is not too abstract and is not Fulton-Harris (which probably has it, too, but is unreadable).

Comment: darij, I think you may be confusing "dominant" with "highest".

Comment: Oh, thanks Scott. Somehow I mistook "dominant" for "highest wrt dominance order".

Answer (score 5):

The question is not well-formulated, as Bugs Bunny observes.   In the case of the special linear group or Lie algebra (say over the field $\mathbb{C}$), it happens to be true that the fundamental dominant weights are precisely the *minuscule* ones (defined by the condition that the weight is nonzero while all pairings with arbitrary positive coroots are 0 or 1), equivalent to being minimal (and nonzero) in the usual partial ordering of dominant weights.  In particular, for an irreducible representation having such a highest weight all its weights are conjugate under the Weyl group, with only the highest weight therefore being dominant.

For irreducible root systems of other than type $A$, the minuscule weights are also fundamental but there are very few of them.    For example, the 0 weight always occurs in irreducible representations for type $G_2$ and rules out existence of minuscule weights.  Bourbaki is the most standard reference (*Groupes et algebres de Lie*, VIII, 7.3), but in textbooks the details are usually left as an exercise.

In type A, it's a standard exercise to compute the highest weights occurring in the various exterior powers of the standard representation (whose highest weight is the first fundamental weight) and see directly that these are minuscule and in particular fundamental.

Comment: I just want to point out a very pretty paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.1091v1 -- I'm not sure it answers the question, but it seems to give a nice way of thinking of minuscule and dominant weights...

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "why"? Do you want a complete proof - it is rather straightforward and an easy exercise.

If you want a moral reason then this is because it is rather small or [miniscule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuscule_representation), to be precise, i.e. its weights form a Weyl group orbit.

Comment: The (peculiar) spelling is actually *minuscule* ("minus", not "mini").  Anyway, the Wikipedia entry chooses an odd reference and gives a nonstandard definition allowing the 0 weight to be called minuscule.   (My preferred term for that variant is "minimal".)   This is usually forbidden.   